# JSON.NET Converting class with custom data types

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET to try and convert a type of Bar to JSON.

```
public class Foo {
    String A;
    String B;
    Int32 C;
    DateTime D;
}

public class Bar {
    String E;
    String F;
    String G;
    Foo H;
}
```

And I'm using this to convert a Bar to JSON.

```
public String ConvertBar(Bar _bar) {
    String Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Bar>(_bar);
    return Result;
}
```

Something like this should be output:

```
{
  "E": "Another Value",
  "F": "Flamingos",
  "G": "Another Another Value",
  "H": [
    {
      "A": "Some Value",
      "B": "Some Other Value",
      "C": 42,
      "D": "2000-01-013T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Whatever I do, the output of `ConvertBar()` is always null. So how are you supposed to convert Bar into JSON while retaining the values of `Foo`? I've heard you have to create a converter but I have no experience in those.

Comment: You should make your properties public and also have a parameterless constructor in both the classes

Comment: Those aren't really the complete classes. They're just the bare bones of what the actual classes on my code contain. I already have the properties public and I already have constructors in place. I'm really just stumped on converting it.

Comment: Now I see that nowhere you are serializing the bar object, you are serializing `MessageJSON` property

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to edit that out. It was a fragment of my actual code. I just copied it to be quicker. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can convert your field to property or Field decorated with [JsonProperty]

```
 public class Foo
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        String A;
        [JsonProperty]
        String B;
        [JsonProperty]
        Int32 C;
        [JsonProperty]
        DateTime D;
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public Bar()
        {
            H = new Foo();
        }
        [JsonProperty]
        String G;
        [JsonProperty]
        Foo H;
        public String E { get; set; }
        public String F { get; set; }
    }
```

After using your ConvertBar function I get following output.

```
{"G":null,"H":{"A":null,"B":null,"C":0,"D":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},"E":null,"F":null}
```